# WPF. How to bind a property to control?

Tags: wpf, binding

**C# code:**

A class `Theme` with a member `Color themeColor` And

`MainWindow` has a member `Theme winTheme`.

**XAML:**

A `Grid`.

I want to bind the `winTheme.themeColor` to the Grid's `Background`.
So that when the variable changes, Grid's background changes automatically...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Actually, I have created a `Theme` class whose member is `Color themeColor` and  `MainWindow`'s member is `Theme winTheme`

So can I do `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding winTheme.themeColor}" />`